# How to scrape all the answers from a particular user on Quora?

Tags: web-scraping, quora

I would like to scrape all the answers from a particular user on Quora.

The problem is, some users have hundreds of answers, so I don't think just using Python's `BeautifulSoup` on their user profile page would work. Also, some answers are quite long and Quora collapses long answers automatically. This means I can't get the full answer text without visiting the question link first.

Is there any clever workaround or API I can use to achieve this?